# How to loop through HttpHeaders in request and add any missing into new header variable

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, httprequest

This is for an angular 6 project.

To start with I call the following method, set a new header and do a get request:

```
public getExposurePageDetailByExposureId(caseId, EditMode): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('EditMode', EditMode);
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url.getExposurePageDetailByExposureIdUrl + "/" + caseId, {headers});
  }
```

Upon the request being processed, it goes through a file `httpInterceptor.ts`. This analyzes a bunch of request information.

In this file it creates a new HttpHeaders variable:

```
var authHeader = "Bearer " + this._cookieService.get('userToken');
var userId =  this._cookieService.get('userId') == "" ? "0": this._cookieService.get('userId');
var centreId =  (this._cookieService.get('centerId') == "" || this._cookieService.get('centerId') == "null")? "0":this._cookieService.get('centerId');
var headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': authHeader,
    'userId':userId,
    'centreId': centreId
  });
```

After this I'd like to compare the current request headers with the new formed `headers` variable.

The idea being that I pick up the `EditMode` header (name and value) and add it into `headers`.

```
//req being the current request being processed with the EditMode header in it.
for(var hd in req.headers){
  if (headers does not contain hd.headername){
    //add header
    headers = headers.set('hd.headername', hd.headervalue);
  }
}
```

How can I form this processing loop?

**EDIT**:
Using the following produces an error:

```
req.headers.keys().forEach(h=> {
              console.log(h);
              console.log(req.headers.get(h));
              })
```

[image]

**Further update**:

The above error was produced by an error handler, so the output isn't very useful, the actual error is as follows:

[image]

Apparently req.headers.keys() cannot be looped over, however when I query the `keys` function in the debugger is returns the following saying that it should return an array:

[image]

By all means, it looks like it should work. 
There are a bunch of other requests that it processes through without issue... probably because none of them anything set in the keys

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of how it could be implemented:

```js
 headers1.keys().forEach(key => {

   if (!headers2.has(key)) headers2.set(key, headers1.get(key))

 })
```

Or even shorter:

```
headers1.keys().forEach(k => !headers2.has(k) && headers2.set(k, headers1.get(k)))
```

Comment: Hi Rafi, I used the forEach on the `headers` variable and it looped through fine, but the forEach doesn't work for the `req.headers.keys()`. Can you think of any reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? what does it return?

Comment: Updated question with details

Comment: It basically bombs out of the typescript function, not sure the error is of any use

Comment: Can I bother you to create a simple online example? thanks

Comment: Rafi, I have added a bit more detail in the above question. And I'm sorry but I wouldn't know how to reproduce the issue in an online example

Comment: what is the type of `EditMode`?

Comment: Rafi, figured it out, your code works perfectly, but when I first set the EditMode which is bool, I need to convert to string. This didn't produce a problem until trying to iterate through the headers